# PHP websocket documentation

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, real-time-data

I love programming using PHP. Recently I've wondered wether to spend more time learning node.js or not. Then I stumbled across PHP websocket. I saw an example making a live chat in websocket, where messages was sent in live time.

However, I can't seem to find any documentation or, better yet, explanation of what this feature actually does! Can anyone explain what PHP websocket does (technically), or send link to the correct documentation?

Wouldn't PHP websocket make it possible to push any type of content in real time to users, just like node.js can? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: "PHP websocket" is not the name of a library or technology. Which websocket library did you come across? Specifying that will help you get the correct answer faster.

Answer (score 2):

**WebSockets** are a bi-directional persistent connection from a web browser to a server.  Read [WebSocket on WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)  and [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

`node.js` and `WebSocket` are 2 different things. `node.js` is programming language built on the Google V8 JavaScript engine, whereas `WebSocket` is communication protocol.

Yes, `WebSocket` can help you push real-time updates to your client.

Here is One of the site that can help you work in `WebSocket` using PHP - http://socketo.me - **Documentation URL** : http://socketo.me/docs/